# Where clause inside whereHas being ignored in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Im trying to make a query using *whereHas* with eloquent. The query is like this:

```
$projects = Project::whereHas('investments', function($q) {
                $q->where('status','=','paid');
            })
            ->with('investments')
            ->get();
```

Im using Laravel 5.2 using a Postgres driver.

The Project model is:

```
public function investments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Investment');
}
```

The investments model has:

```
public function project() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Project');
}
```

The projects table has fields id,fields...

The investments table has the fields id,project_id,status,created_at

My issue is that the query runs and returns a collection of the projects which have at least one investment, however the *where* clause inside the *whereHas* is ignored, because the resulting collection includes investments with status values different than *paid*.

Does anyone has any idea of what is going on?

Comment: Drop the `->with('investments')`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I tried that but if I do then I receive only a collection with the projects which comply with the investment restrictions, however I need the projects and its corresponding investments.

Comment: Ahh, I see. It might be because there's no `return` statement in the `whereHas`?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy thanks! I tried that already) also like this: `$projects = Project::whereHas('investments', function($q) {
                return $q->where('status','=','paid');
            })
            ->with('investments')
            ->get();` and also `$projects = Project::whereHas('investments', function($q) {
                $q->where('status','=','paid');
                return $q
            })
            ->with('investments')
            ->get();` and the results are the same: the where clause is ignored, the collection returns the projects with investments no matter its status.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is what you need

```
$projects = Project::whereHas('investments', function($q) { 
          $q->where('status','=','paid'); 
     })->with(['investments' => function($q) { 
          $q->where('status','=','paid'); 
     }])->get();
```

`whereHas` wil check all projects that have `paid` investments, `with` will eagerload all those investments.

Answer (score 4):

You're confusing `whereHas` and `with`.

The `with` method will let you load the relationship only if the query returns true.

The `whereHas` method will let you get only the models which have the relationship which returns true to the query.

So you need to only use `with` and not mix with with `whereHas`:

```
$projects = Project::with(['investments' => 
function($query){ $query->where('status','=','paid'); }])
->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$projects = Project::with('investments')->whereHas('investments', function($q) {
                $q->where('status','like','paid'); //strings are compared with wildcards.
            })
            ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks and I tried, however I still receive a projects collection with an investments collection like this:` "investments": [
          {
            "id": 52,
            "user_id": 55,
            "total": "50000",
            "currency": "MXN",
            "status": "created",
            "updated_at": "2017-04-08 03:28:24"
          },
          {
            "id": 53,
            "user_id": 55,
            "total": "100000",
            "currency": "MXN",
            "status": "paid",
            "updated_at": "2017-04-09 23:09:58"
          }
        ]`

Comment: In Project.php Model try added extra parameters: `public function investments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Investment','project_id','id');
}`

Comment: I tried it and still the same result. However if I do a query with a different field say: `$projects = Project::with('investments')
                ->whereHas('investments', function($q) {
                    $q->where('user_id', '=', 56); 
                    return $q;
                })
                ->get();` I get the proper result. The issue seems to be when I try to filter by a string field.

Comment: Then are you sure you have `paid` values in `status` column?

Answer (score 1):

Change the order. Use with() before the whereHas(). I had a similar problem few weeks ago. Btw, is the only real difference between the problem and the functional example that you made.